# QGIS - Countif function

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, sql

I have a simple attribute table structured in this way:

| Features | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 | Attribute4 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| F2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| F3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| F4 | 12 | 4 | 6 | 9 | 4 |

And I need to populate the 'Count' field depending on how many attributes have a value different from 0. In Excel I would use a simple `Countif` function such as `Countif(Attribute1:Attribute4; "<>0")`. In QGIS I tried to use this:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attribute1 <> 0 THEN 1 END) +
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attribute2 <> 0 THEN 1 END) +
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attribute3 <> 0 THEN 1 END) +
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attribute4 <> 0 THEN 1 END) +
```

but I don't get the right result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This expression gives you what you need:

```
with_variable(
  'ar', array(Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4),
  array_length(@ar) - array_count(@ar, 0)
)
```

`with_variable` assigns the second argument to the first argument to use it in the third argument that is an expression.

```
ar = array(Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4)
```

`array_length(@ar)` returns the length of the array. `array_count(@ar, 0)` counts the number of occurrences of a given value in the array. And  `array_length(@ar) - array_count(@ar, 0)` gives you the number of fields that are different from 0.

[image]

Comment: Where will you save this information? We added the previous value as a new column to the records in the table.

Comment: You can open a new thread for this question