# QGIS - Countif function on columns

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, sql

In [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/454322/qgis-countif-function) I asked for a substitute of the 'Countif' function in Excel to be used to populate a field depending on how many values different from 0 were present in the several attributes for every feature.

Now I would like to know if a similar result can be applied also to colums and not to rows.

To resume the previous example, with a similar table

| Features | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 | Attribute4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| F2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| F3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| F4 | 12 | 4 | 6 | 9 |

I would like to get the count of how many values are different from 0 considering **the columns**; that would mean 3 for Attribute1, 2 for Attribute2, 2 for Attribute3, 3 for Attribute4.

Answer (score 4):

You can aggregate the values in an array, filter all elements greater than 0 and then get the length of the filtered array:

Use this expression in the field calculator on the layer itself:

```
array_length(
    array_filter(
        array_agg("Attribute1"),
        @element > 0
    )
)
```

If you want to calculate this in a different attribute table than the layer of interest, you can use the `aggregate` function in the field calculator of the other layer and specify the name of the layer of interest:

```
array_length(
    array_filter(
        aggregate(
            'layer_name',       -- the layer of interest
            'array_agg',        -- aggregate values into an arrray
            "Attribute1"
        ),
        @element > 0
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am in doubt on how to apply it. Should I use the field calculator? And about the second example, should I create a table ('layer_name') before?

Comment: Indeed in the field calculator, I will clarify my answer.

Comment: sorry if I ask again but it seems not to work as expected, also because I would need the results for all the four attributes. And how would they be displayed using the field calculator? As a new (virtual) field? But in this case results would be structured in columns as if they were associated to features, not to attributes. I'm missing something.